# How to get all the web apps' URLs / URL list in azure portal site

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

If there are many web-apps and all have the custom domain.

How to get all the web apps' URLs / URL list in azure portal site?

Comment: Why not use Poweshell `Get-AzureRmWebApp | Select-Object Name,HostNames`?

Comment: Finally, I used this command and get what I want.
`Get-AzureRmWebApp | foreach-object {$_} | select-object SiteName,DefaultHostName,ResourceGroup`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I used this command and get what I want.

`Get-AzureRmWebApp | foreach-object {$_} | select-object SiteName,DefaultHostName,ResourceGroup`

Comment: This wasn't from Azure CLI, was it? Doesn't seem to do the trick for me, if it is!