# How to get a list of all the web apps on Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-webapps

I am trying to export a list of all the web applications on Azure. I can do it for one Subscriptions, but I am trying to run it for all the subscriptions. My code below is getting all the subscriptions, but not getting the app service or web app from those subscriptions. Any idea or suggestion

```
   $Subscriptions = Get-AzSubscription
       foreach ($sub in $Subscriptions) {
           Get-AzSubscription -SubscriptionName $sub.Name | Set-AzContext
           Get-AzWebApp | foreach-object {$_} | select-object SiteName, DefaultHostName, ResourceGroup
           }
```

Note: This is not a duplicate question, I have checked this link - [How to get all the web apps' URLs / URL list in azure portal site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50691489/how-to-get-all-the-web-apps-urls-url-list-in-azure-portal-site..). It doesn't work.

Note: This one is also - [Powershell script to fetch Azure WebApp details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58437227/powershell-script-to-fetch-azure-webapp-details)

Comment: Run the `Get-AzWebApp` command for one site. Look at the properties on the object that's returned. Do you see the properties you're looking for? There's nothing wrong with the code you wrote (although piping to `foreach-object` in this case is redundant).

Comment: Daniel is right - the code you provided does work. If it's not returning what you expect it could be your permissions inside the current subscription.

Comment: Do you see any errors? Or just blank output?

Answer (score 0):

Even if code in OP is correct, I found it causing duplicates due to having multiple tenants.

Adding `-TenantId` prevents such issue:

```
$Subscriptions = Get-AzSubscription
foreach ($sub in $Subscriptions) {
    Get-AzSubscription -SubscriptionName $sub.Name -TenantId $sub.TenantId | Set-AzContext
    # Do whatever is required here
}
```